# How to show value from laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have tables like this

```
products - id, name, description, category_id, brand_id, color_id, material_id, price
extras - id, product_id, size_id, stock
images - id, product_id, name, path
size - id, name
```

Model product :

```
public function extra()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Extra', 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function image()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Model extra :

```
public function size()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Size', 'id', 'size_id');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongTo('App\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Model image :

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

how to get the size name, image name & path value from the extras and images tables?
I can get the size name using this query **echo $product['extra'][0]['size']['name'];**, but I only get one value I don't know how to loop to get all the value.

```
$products = Product::with(['brand', 'category', 'color', 'image', 'material', 'extra', 'user'])->get();
foreach ($products as $product)
{
echo $product['name'] ." ". strip_tags($product['description']) ." ". $product['category']['name'] ." ". $product['brand']['name'] ." ". $product['color']['name'] ." ". $product['material']['name'] ." ". $product['price'] ." ". $product['sku'] ." ". $product['user']['name'] ."</br>";
echo $product['extra'][0]['size']['name'];
}
```

Any suggestion what I need to do or something that I can read to solve thiat? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe below code will work for you :

```
// Extra relationship in Product.php
public function extra()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\extra', 'product_id', 'id');
}

// To get product extra with eager loading 
$products = Product::with(['extra', 'extra.size'])->get();

foreach ($products as $product)
{
  foreach ($product->extra as $extra){
    echo $extra->size->name
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how about the image value, what I want for image value becomes one row with the product data. 1 product has many images. How to do that? Because if I do the same thing for the image the result will become like this :
name, etc, size, image1;
name, etc, size, image2;
name, etc, size, image3;

what I want is :
name, etc, size, image1, image2, image3;

Comment: foreach ($products as $product)
{
  foreach ($product->image as $sinleImage){
    echo $sinleImage->name;
    echo $sinleImage->path
  }
}

Comment: it is not working, I tried then the result is the same become like this: name, etc, size, image1; name, etc, size, image2; name, etc, size, image3;

Comment: @gigi your question is bit confusing Please elaborate. ( How about the image value, what I want for image value becomes one row with the product data. 1 product has many images. How to do that? )

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. I will try to explain so right now if I execute the program the result is product name, etc, size, image1; product name, etc, size, image2;. What I need is product name, etc, size, image1, image2;. I will use that data to show in the datatables. can the explanation be understood? and sorry if the explanation confusing you. Or any suggestion about the database design? should I just put the data image with product table so I can remove the image table?

Comment: @gigi Please share with code my with me, OR draw your requirement on paper and send it me then I will be able to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The product contains multiple values of each relation you implement 'with' so run foreach loop or try this for a specific result
$products-brand->where("SOME CONDITION")->get();